# How to convert all warnings.warn to logging

Tags: python

I have whole configuration to log and process all messages through logging. Ideally, I would like to convert all warnings to logging warnings so that I can see them in the collected logs. Currently they are juts displayed on stderr.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding it sounds like you simply need to run a search and replace? An IDE like PyCharm can really help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I realized this is even mentioned in `warnings` documentation. You have to just do:

```
logging.captureWarnings(True)
```